# PropTypes giving error no matter if the type is right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm using React with PropTypes and hooks

> "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
>
> "react": "^16.11.0",

And I have a component that receives an object with some data from the database. Then, testing the data:

```
{ console.log('Carousel reciving: ', typeof informations, informations) }
```

Gives the following console log:

```
Carousel reciving:  object (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Data is sent to the component by the call:

```
<Carousel informations={informations} isLoading={isLoading} />
```

And the component:

```
const Carousel = ({ informations, isLoading }) => (
    <ReactPlaceholder ...some props />...some content</ReactPlaceholder>
) // Carousel
```

But no matter if I change the PropType to array or object, it still giving the following error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `informations` of type `array` supplied to `Carousel`, expected `object`.

If I change to PropType.object.isRequired, the error says that the value provided is of type array. And if I change to PropType.array.isRequired, the error says that the value provided is of type object:

```
Carousel.propTypes = {
    informations: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
} // propTypes
```

I know I could use the fetch function inside the component, but this data is shared with other components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `console.log`, `informations` is in fact an array of objects; it's logging as `[{…}, {…},` note the opening `[`.

So you want to change your `propTypes` to

```
Carousel.propTypes = {
    informations: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    isLoading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: I didn't know that, but I changed and still giving the error - Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `informations` of type `object` supplied to `Carousel`, expected an array.

Comment: My initial state was starting with `useState({})`, then before the data fetch from the database it was trying to render an object, not an array. So I changed to `useState([{}])`. Now is working as expected. thx.

Comment: Now I know why ESlint aways gives a warning message by using an object or array as PropType. Because you don't know what is inside the object/array. Using arrayOf(some proptype) we can predict the inner values type.